# How can I setup a C program with nothing but a makefile and the source, to be debugged with QtCreator?

Tags: c, makefile, gdb, qt-creator

QtCreator does a lot to streamline the process of using GDB, and I would like to learn how I could use it when working on a strictly C project, that has at most, a makefile for its project settings.

I don't think you need a project file such as QMake or CMake, because I had heard another user was using this as their System debugger. However if I do, that would not be the end of the world. As long as I can set breakpoints and do backtracing, I will be satisfied.

Comment: Make sure that you compile your code using -g (include debug symbols) and -O0 (no optimizations) and you should be good to go.  If your executable is `foo' then on the command line `gdb foo', and you should be good to go.  As a note, I never use QtCreator - I always use just a make file and gdb for debugging.  I do have emacs set up so I can use gdb inside emacs.

Comment: Did you check if QtCreator can create a project with an existing Makefile? Other IDEs can do this. -- I understand that you like to do this, because debugging in a GUI is simpler than via the TUI of GDB, but hey, many use just the latter.

Comment: @thurizas I never expect things to be that easy, but it really was, just that easy. Your answer if you give one, is more or less accepted.